# how to draw images in a .NET Interactive notebook (C#, VS Code)

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-code, jupyter, dotnet-interactive

I'm trying to draw simple graphics in the .NET Interactive Notebook, using C#.  Kind of like a C# version of Dr. Racket.

The simplest thing I've seen so far is `using System.Drawing`  (SFML.NET, Raylib-cs work too, but they open up a window to show graphics instead of within the notebook).

I'd be willing to try another recommendation with `#r "nuget:<whatever>"` too.

The problem seems to be related to the MIME type, but I'm not sure.  I get the same results with both `.dib` and `.ipynb`

Is there a way to use something like `.Display()` and show the simple image within the notebook?

**Code**

```csharp
using System.Drawing;

//Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 800, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
graphics.DrawArc(pen, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 20);

//bitmap.Save("DrawArc.png");
//display(bitmap);

bitmap.Display();
```

**Output**

```html
Tag PhysicalDimension   Size    Width   Height  HorizontalResolution    VerticalResolution  Flags   RawFormat   PixelFormat PropertyIdList  PropertyItems   FrameDimensionsList Palette
<null>
{ {Width=200, Height=200}: IsEmpty: False, Width: 200, Height: 200 }
{ {Width=200, Height=200}: IsEmpty: False, Width: 200, Height: 200 }
200
200
96
96
2
{ MemoryBMP: Guid: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e }
Format32bppArgb
[ ]
[ ]
[ 7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483 ]
{ System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette: Flags: 0, Entries: [ ] }
```

**Output 2 (using a VS Code Plugin 'Simple Notebook Renderers')**

```
<table><thead><tr><th>Tag</th><th>PhysicalDimension</th><th>Size</th><th>Width</th><th>Height</th><th>HorizontalResolution</th><th>VerticalResolution</th><th>Flags</th><th>RawFormat</th><th>PixelFormat</th><th>PropertyIdList</th><th>PropertyItems</th><th>FrameDimensionsList</th><th>Palette</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><div class="dni-plaintext">&lt;null&gt;</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">{ {Width=200, Height=200}: IsEmpty: False, Width: 200, Height: 200 }</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">{ {Width=200, Height=200}: IsEmpty: False, Width: 200, Height: 200 }</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">200</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">200</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">96</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">96</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">2</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">{ MemoryBMP: Guid: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e }</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">Format32bppArgb</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">[  ]</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">[  ]</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">[ 7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483 ]</div></td><td><div class="dni-plaintext">{ System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette: Flags: 0, Entries: [  ] }</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer on github's issues. It looks like someone made a Skiasharp extension too, which is more what I'm looking for (although I cannot figure out how to install it):

https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/902#issuecomment-900918386

**Updated/Fixed Code**

```csharp
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Formatting;

MemoryStream memStream;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

void d()
{
    memStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    string base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
    display(PocketViewTags.img[src: "data:image/png;base64," + base64str]);
}

Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 9);
graphics.DrawArc(pen, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 120);

d();
```

[image]

### *Update*

I think I've found a better way while trying stuff out.  (also posted the same thing over at the github issues)
...digging around the docs and tooling around, it looks like `SKSurface` Class has a `.Snapshot()` method that works in the notebook without any added extensions.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.sksurface?view=skiasharp-2.80.2

Also, the `display` command doesn't seem to work anymore in the notebook.  The notebooks seem to have their own `.Display()` method.  I'm guessing because all this stuff is so new its hard to find documentation for n00bs like me?

```
#r "nuget: SkiaSharp"
using SkiaSharp;

SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo(256, 256);
SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create(info);
SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

// configure our brush
SKPaint redBrush = new SKPaint {
    Color = new SKColor(0xff, 0, 0),
    IsStroke = true
};
SKPaint blueBrush = new SKPaint {
    Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 0xff),
    IsStroke = true
};

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i += 8) {
    SKRect rect = new SKRect(i, i, 256 - i - 1, 256 - i - 1);
    canvas.DrawRect(rect, (i % 16 == 0) ? redBrush : blueBrush);
}

surface.Snapshot().Display();
```

[image]

Comment: my vscode cannot find Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.Formatting