# vscode .net interactive notebooks to display latex

Tags: visual-studio-code, interactive, c#-interactive, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

I have been looking for a way to display `latex` in `vscode` .Net interactive notebooks, but I've had no luck.

on my C# .Net interactive Code Cell I have

```
#r "nuget: AngouriMath.Interactive, 1.3.0"
using AngouriMath.Interactive;
using AngouriMath;
Entity entity= "X^2+1";
var latexText = entity.Latexise();
display(latextText,"text/latex") //<< this will not work because "text/latex" mimetype is not valid.
```

I found this for `image` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850956/7197556 where the bitmap image is converted to `base64string` before being passed to the `display()` function. Is there a way to do this for `latex`? or are there any other straightforward solutions?

side-note: I'd like to avoid writing javascript/html code cells as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using visualization for AngouriMath

You should be able to do it without `display`. In Notebooks you can visualize any expression just by running a cell with it, see the screenshot

[image]

By the way, there's still some problem with support of F# in .NET Interactive extensions, so the kernel might fail to load. In case it fails, you can either activate it manually:

```fs
AngouriMath.InteractiveExtension.KernelExtension.applyMagic()
```

Or install the last preview version:

```
#i "https://www.myget.org/F/angourimath/api/v3/index.json"
#r "nuget:AngouriMath.Interactive, 0.0.0-*"
```

### Using Interactive LaTeX visualization

If you want to display LaTeX without AngouriMath, you can use `MathString`. Just create an instance of it, and it will be displayed for you:

[image]

Comment: interesting, i think this is what i was looking for, gotta try your answer once i get home from work, thanks.